# Smarty {php} tag issue: Need suggestions for more productive migration from old Smarty to v4.3.1

Tags: php, smarty

I'm helping a friend to migrate their PHP project to the latest **PHP 8.2.4**. As he also uses **Smarty v2.6.19**, I'll have to help him to upgrade to **v4.3.1**, which is the latest version of Smarty. Unfortunately, his old PHP project is using too many `.tpl` files **(around 800+ files)** that contain the `{php}` tags. I tried the following but no luck:

```
class SmartyWrap extends Smarty
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); 
        /* 
          This is not working either.
        $my_security_policy = new Smarty_Security($this);
        $my_security_policy->allow_php_tag = true;
        $this->enableSecurity($my_security_policy); */

        $this->allow_php_templates = true; // This one not working too
        $this->allow_php_tag = true; // I don't think this property even exists in 4.3.1
        /**
         * register_modifier() is deprecated.
         */
        // $this->register_modifier('unserialize', 'unserialize');
        $this->registerPlugin("modifier", "unserialize", "unserialize");
    }
}
```

The same error still appears:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "something.tpl" on
> line 3 "{php}" unknown tag 'php' <-- thrown in something.tpl on line 3

I understand that putting the `{php}` inside the templates defeats the `SoC` principles of Smarty, but due to the large number of `.tpl` files that involve this, is there a safer and more productive way to perform this migration? Any advice is welcome!

### UPDATE:

To help you provide a better input, below is one of the examples that 800+ `.tpl` files are doing:

```
{php}
   global $objA, $objB;
{/php}

<table>
   <tr>
       <td>{php}echo $objA->method1(param1, param2);{/php}</td>
       <td>{php}echo $objB->method2(param1, param2, param3);{/php}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

It looks like those `.tpl` files do not have any multiple lines block PHP logic such as `foreach` except those one line `echo` statements and the `global` declaration at the top of each file.